# Socket Programming For Out Of Local Network In C

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I want to send data over the network to a specific Target (Laptop) so I have the public IP of the target for example 2.133.167.57 Private IP of the adapter: 192.168.1.1 and MAC: CC:AB:C2:18:72:63 and the specific target is listening for my connection;
the thing that we need as far as I know to connect to a specific target is Public IP, Private IP(maybe), MACAddress.

I checked my Public IP address using both my laptop and phone at https://www.whatismyip.com and both of them were the same as it should be (as far as I didn't use VPN Services for them).
let's take a look at struct sockaddr_in:

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    sin_family;
    sin_port;
    sin_addr;
}
```

The modem which my target connected to has one public IP and they are few devices that using this public IP (let's consider they don't use VPN) so if I enter only the target's public IP in sin_addr It won't be sent to my target and so now I have to add a MAC address or adapter's private IP to make the connection more accurate but how?

How I can add in addition to public IP, the MAC, or Private Ip?

Which function or structs should I use to make a connection between two laptops on different network?

Comment: What you're trying to do won't work. You need to set port forwarding in your NAT.

Comment: looks like a general computing problem. This cannot be really fixed in just C

Comment: @tkausl thanks, mate.it helped a lot but a question: why for a connection between two laptops need port forwarding but in connection with servers we don't use it?

Comment: Because routers aren't behind a NAT. Your home network shares one and only one public IP address, accessed through your router (a NAT), servers have their own public IP and are connected directly to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

> the thing that we need as far as I know to connect to a specific target is Public IP, Private IP(maybe), MACAddress

No. If you want to establish a TCP connection, you only need one single IP address, and a port number. Anyway you have no direct way to give a secondary (private) IP or mac address in the `connect` call.

But you must be sure that the equipment holding the public IP address will know what to do with your incoming connection. When there is a difference between public and private IP addresse, it generally means that you have a kind of gateway providing Network Address Translation (Internet Providers boxes often do that). It automatically handles outgoing connections by replacing the original IP address by its own one, and passing back responses to the original machine. But for incoming connections, it must **explicitely** be instructed to pass calls to a specific port to a specific machine, because by default, it normally rejects everything.

Comment: To clarify, "explicitly instructed to pass calls to a specific port to a specific machine" usually means the gateway device's owner has to log in to the gateway device's settings GUI and manually set up Port Forwarding for the specified port (i.e. it's not usually something that can be done programatically)